# how to detect if the sprite has been clicked in pygame

Tags: python, sprite, pygame

I'm new in pygame, right now I'm working with sprites. My question is how do I detect if the sprite has been clicked? I want to do something when the sprite was clicked as if it were a button.

Thank you.

[Edited]

Thank you, Stephen. In addition is there a way to know who is the sprite that was clicked? Here is sample code:

```
boxes = pygame.sprite.Group()
for color, location in [([255, 0, 0], [0, 0]),
                        ([0, 255, 0], [60, 60]),
                        ([0, 0, 255], [120, 120])]:
    boxes.add(UpDownBox(color, location)
```

For example I click the sprite in location [0,0], the program should print its colour or its location.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's been a long time since I did anything in Pygame, but IIRC the basic idea is that your sprite should have a `rect` [attribute](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) that describes its position on the screen.  When you receive a mouse click event, you [get the position](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos) by calling `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`.  You can then [check for a collision](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect) between a `rect` centered at the mouse position and your sprite's rect by calling `pygame.sprite.collide_rect()` on both `rect` objects.

A good example can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130417012710/http://rene.f0o.com/mywiki/LectureFour).

Comment: Alas, example link no longer valid.

Answer (score 6):

Simpler: [Rect.collidepoint(x,y)](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#Rect.collidepoint)

## main loop

```
#in event handling:
if event.type == MOUSEMOTION: x,y = event.pos

for box in boxes:
    if box.rect.collidepoint(x,y): print 'yay!'
```

There are several more collision functions in both *Rect* and *Sprite*. See:

- http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide
- http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html
- http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html