# How to detect when a rectangular object, image or sprite is clicked

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm trying to tell when a sprite, which must be part of a particular group (`pygame.sprite.Group()`), is clicked on. Currently I've tried creating a sprite which is just the mouses position and totally invisible, adding it to its own group, and using this code:

`clickedList = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(guess1, mice, False)`

where `guess1` is the sprite getting clicked on and `mice` is the group containing the sprite that has the position of the mouse.

When I try this, I am told that "Group has no attribute rect". Where do I go from here?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `guess1` is a `Sprite` instance? It doesn't look like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to detect if the sprite has been clicked in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356840/how-to-detect-if-the-sprite-has-been-clicked-in-pygame)

Comment: @sloth It is a ```pygame.sprite.Group()``` Do I need to use the sprite itself?

Comment: @Valentino No, the example linked in the answer is gone, and I don't quite get what the rest of it is saying, because that's pretty much what I'm doing, at least as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've a sprite (`my_sprite`) and you want to verify if the mouse is on the sprite, then you've to get the `.rect` attribute of the [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) object and to test if the mouse is in the rectangular area by `.collidepoint()`:

```py
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
if my_sprite.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
    # [...]
```

The Sprites in a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) can iterate through. So the test can be done in a loop:

```py
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
for sprite in mice:
    if sprite.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        # [...]
```

Or get a list of the Sprites within the Group, where the mouse is on it. If the Sprites are not overlapping, then the list will contain 0 or 1 element:

```py
mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
clicked_list = [sprite for sprite in mice if sprite.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos)]

if any(clicked_list):
    clicked_sprite = clicked_list[0]
    # [...]
```

Comment: I'm Using the second one, but it always returns as false.         ```mousePos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()                               for Circle in guess1:
                    if Circle.rect.collidepoint(mousePos):
                        ##...``` Is it possible the issue is with the sprite itself rather than the condition, or am I just missing something stupid here? (sorry about the code, it won't format properly in comments.)

Comment: I'm using this to define the class ```class Circles(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self, value, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.value = value
        circleImage = pygame.image.load ("Outline.png")
        if value == 11:
            circleImage = pygame.image.load ("Unknown.png")
        self.image = pygame.Surface([40,40])
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.image.blit(circleImage,(0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y``` and drawing using ```display.flip```

Comment: If its easier, I've got all the code in a google doc [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZCX5dvy5gbvM6qJhoKeRBuMK72YIw00PffiyCgoe01E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yes, it is a group.

Comment: @Nico But it seems to work fine `guess1` are the 4 circles in the 2nd row. If you want to change the color of the circles, then you've to add `self.image.blit(circleImage,(0,0))` at the end of `changeColour`

Comment: I've put the circles in the wrong places. Thank you so much for helping.