# I am making a Whack a Mole game where user gets a point when he clicks the mole image. I am unable to figure out how to make that happen

Tags: python, pygame

So i am making this whack a mole game. I am able to make mole appear in random locations in the game however i cant understand how to award the player a point when he clicks on the mole. As the mole appears randomly it is possible that it appears on the same location twice. How would i stop this from happening. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import MOUSEBUTTONDOWN
import random
import time

pygame.init()

# constants
width = 300
height = 300
z = 2
Radius = 21

# loading mole image
mole_image = pygame.image.load("mole image2.png")
modified_image = pygame.transform.scale(mole_image, (40, 40))

# burrow and mole positions
burrow_x = -50
burrow_y = 50
count = int(0)
burrow_positions_list = []
mole_positions_list = []
while count != 9:
    count += 1
    burrow_x += 100
    if burrow_x == 350:
        burrow_x -= 300
        burrow_y += 100
    tuple1 = (burrow_x, burrow_y)
    tuple2 = (burrow_x - 20, burrow_y - 20)
    burrow_positions_list.append(tuple1)
    mole_positions_list.append(tuple2)

# colours
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# setting up the display
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Whack A Mole")


# creating burrows for the moles
def Burrows():
    circle_count = int(-1)
    while circle_count != len(burrow_positions_list) - 1:
        circle_count += 1
        pygame.draw.circle(display, black, burrow_positions_list[circle_count], 30)


def Moles():
    display.blit(modified_image, random.choice(mole_positions_list))
    time.sleep(z)


# running pygame until quit
run = True
while run:
    # speeding up mole blitting
    z -= 0.05
    if z < 0.4:
        z += 0.05
    display.fill(white)
    Burrows()
    Moles()
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to detect if the sprite has been clicked in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356840/how-to-detect-if-the-sprite-has-been-clicked-in-pygame)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the list of burrow positions:

```
burrow_positions_list[]
```

At each of which you draw a circle, radius 30.  First let's convert that 30 into a constant.

```
BURROW_RADIUS = WINDOW_WIDTH // 10  # scales with window size, default 30
```

You already know the position when the mouse is clicked:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()          # <-- HERE
```

So now we need to marry the two together.  We know where the burrow centre is, so if the mouse-click is within `BURROW_RADIUS` pixels of this point, it's a hit.

There's a formula for calculating the line distance between points known as the [Euclidian Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance).  For 2 points it's pretty easy:

```
def twoPointDistance( point_a, point_b ):
    x1, y1 = point_a
    x2, y2 = point_b
    x_squared = (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)
    y_squared = (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)
    length = math.sqrt( x_squared + y_squared )
    return length
```

So now we have two points - `burrow_point` and `mouse_click_point`, and a way of determining the distance.  So when a click happens, we just need to see if it was close enough.

```
elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    mouse_click_point = pygame.mouse.get_pos()          # Mouse was clicked
    # Loop through every burrow point, checking the distance
    for i, burrow_point in enumerate( burrow_positions_list ):
        if ( twoPointDistance( mouse_click_point, burrow_point ) < BURROW_RADIUS ):
            # Burrow was clicked
            print( "Burrow %d was clicked" % ( i ) )
```

And that's it.

However...

It would be much less CPU-intensive to pre-calculate a bounding square around each burrow, and only check if the point was inside this (which is only a few simple < / > checks) rather than the complicated maths of square-roots.  There's even a [pre-existing function](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) for it: `pygame.Rect.collidepoint()`.  But this is left as an exercise for the reader!